# PHP replace data only in one column of csv

Tags: php, csv, replace

I need to replace the values only from the third column in my csv. And no where else.
Column 3 of my csv contains only a 'J' or a'N' and i need to change them to '5' or '0'. But right now i it changes always all found N's and J#s in the whole file. But i need it only updated in the third column.

I use the following code to open and rewrite my csv. But it writes always all found Letters to 5 or 0.

```
$csvfile = 'csvfile.csv';
if (file_exists($csvfile)) {
        unlink($csvfile);
    echo "Alte $csvfile entfernt!";
} else {
    echo "Keine alte $csvfile vorhanden";
}

$row = 0;
$fp = fopen('csvfile.csv', 'w');
if (($handle = fopen("oldCSV.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 200000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $dataold = ['J', 'N'];                                                            
    $datanew = ['5', '0'];
    echo "<p> $num Felder in Zeile $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        fputs($fp, str_replace($dataold, $datanew, $data[$c] . "\n"));
    }
  }
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: remove `for` loop, `str_replace` only `$data[2]`

Comment: Indeed, don't for, just do $data[2] the whole time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {

    $data[2] = str_replace(['J', 'N'], ['5', '0'], $data[2]);

    fputcsv($fp, $data);

    echo "<p> ".count($data)." Felder in Zeile ".$row++.": <br /></p>\n";
}
```

**EDIT**

1. I removed `!== FALSE` part from `while` to not compare result with false each time, finally `fgetcsv()` will return false itself and stop the loop
2. collapsed `str_replace` and its' arguments-arrays (for readability only)
3. removed `for` loop to change only 3rd (`[2]`) coloumn
4. got rid of `$num` variable

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: no. doesn't work. at least not for me. it throws also a ',' in all empty fields in the 4. column but doesn't change the Letters to the desired numbers in column 3.
unfortunately also the other suggestions seems not to work for me.

Comment: I have to correct me. This solution works as it should be. my mistake was that i saved the 'oldSCV' with a';' as separator. so i had to change it in my code too.

`while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 200000, ";"))`

so thanks all your help. :)

Comment: yep, I removed 2nd and 3rd parameters in my answer, cause they're default therefore excessive in your example, but if you have `;` separator don't abandon them

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of ways and you might get lots of answers.  Here's one:

```
switch($data[2]) {
    case 'J':
        $data[2] = '5';
        break;
    case 'N':
        $data[2] = '0';
        break;
}
fputcsv($fp, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through each column of your CSV. Why not just deal with the specific column? A simple ternary could do this

```
$data[2] = ($data[2] == 'J') ? '5' : '0';
```

Comment: @vladkras According to the OP, the column has only two values

Comment: correct. in the third column are all fields filled with N or J.