# How to change all values in a column of a csv file to a specific value php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file that looks something like this (there are many more rows):

```
Jim,jim@email.com,8882,456
Bob,bob@email.com,8882,343
```

What I want to do is to change all the values in the fourth column,`456,343` to 500.

I'm new to php and am not sure how to do this.
I have tried

```
<?php
$file = fopen('myfile.csv', 'r+');
$toBoot = array();
while ($data = fgetcsv($file)) {
    echo $data[3];
    $data[3] = str_replace($data[3],'500');
    array_push($toBoot, $data);


}
//print_r($toBoot);
echo $toBoot[0][3];
fputcsv($file, $toBoot);
fclose($file)

?>
```

But it prints

```
Jim,jim@email.com,8882,456
Bob,bob@email.com,8882,343
Array,Array
```

not

```
 Jim,jim@email.com,8882,500
 Bob,bob@email.com,8882,500
```

I've looked at this post, [PHP replace data only in one column of csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921272/php-replace-data-only-in-one-column-of-csv) but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This line looks wrong: `$data[3] = str_replace($data[3],'500');`. Why don't you just replace the value like this: `$data[3] = 500;` ?

Comment: Can you not do that in Excel, it would be so much simpler

Comment: @Karol Samborski That just appends Array,Array,Array to the end of the file

Comment: If that is your actual code, and the actual output, then I am struck by the fact that `echo $data[3];` seems to be outputting "Jim,jim@email.com,8882,456" and "Bob,bob@email.com,8882,343".  I would be quite curious to see the actual source file.

Comment: @RiggsFolly its on a web server

Comment: Then use @KarolSamborski suggestion

Comment: it outputs 456343500

Comment: Purpose of fputcsv is to append a csv line to a file. So you need some loop: `foreach ($toBoot as $line) { fputcsv($file, $line); }`

Comment: Please update your question to clarify what the _output_ is vs what the new _contents of the file_ are.

Comment: @ Karol Samborski Thank you! the for loop worked and my problem is solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace and replace all values at once and not loop each line of the CSV file.

Two lines of code is all that is needed.

```
$csv = file_get_contents($path);
file_put_contents($path, preg_replace("/(.*),\d+/", "$1,500", $csv));
```

Where $path is the path and to the CSV file.

You can see it in action here: https://3v4l.org/Mc3Pm

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to way to solve your problem would be:

```
foreach (file("old_file.csv") as $line)
{
    $new_line = preg_replace('/^(.*),[\d]+/', "$1,500", $line);
    file_put_contents("new_file.csv", $new_line, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To change one field of the CSV, just assign to that array element, you don't need to use any kind of replace function.

```
$data[3] = "500";
```

`fputcsv()` is used to write *one* line to a CSV file, not the entire file at once. You need to call it in a loop. You also need to go back to the beginning of the file and remove the old contents.

```
fseek($file, 0);
ftruncate($file, 0);
foreach ($toBoot as $row) {
    fputcsv($file, $row);
}
```